# How to print values of float tuple in list in integer?

Tags: python-3.x

```
list = [(769.0, ), (806.0, )]
```

In above case, I want to print only 769, 806.

How to print tuple's from list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is how to print the first element in list of tuples?

For a list of tuples with length 2, and you do not care about the 2nd element.

```
for (fp, _) in list:
    print(fp)
```

For a list of tuples with arbitrary tuple length.

```
for x in list:
    print(x[0])
```